# Getting total elapsedTime (TIME) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Please take a look at my table:

[image]

I need to count the total 'code1' and total 'code2' and the total of combine code1 and code2 and  the total elapsedTime per day (timefiledate). Please see this output I am getting:

[image]

Here's my query:

```
 SELECT 
        `Date`,
        `Code1`,
        `Code2`,
        `Total`
    FROM   
    (
        SELECT 
            timefiledate AS `Date`, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE transactionCode= 'code1' AND timefiledate = `date`)AS code1,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE transactionCode= 'code2' AND timefiledate = `date`)AS code2, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE transactionCode IN ('code1', 'code2') AND timefiledate = `date`)AS Total
            #Total elapsedTime goes here
        FROM bartran

    ) AS A

    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31'
    GROUP BY `date`;
```

Take note that elapsedTime type is 'TIME'. I am having trouble getting the total elapsedTime for the entire month. Please can someone give me an advise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you expect your total elapsed time to exceed 839 hours per month? (I know there's only 744 hours maximum in a month, but if you are summing multiple time-elapsed sources, it could be possible.)

Comment: yes, this will surely exceed 839 hours because it is for all the employees working time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the total in seconds, use the time_to_sec function - like so:

```
SELECT sum(time_to_sec(elapsedTime))
FROM tableName 
WHERE transactionCode IN ('code1', 'code2') AND timefiledate = `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to convert TIME to seconds:

```
SELECT 
        `Date`,
        `Code1`,
        `Code2`,
        `Total`,
        `TotalElapsedTime`
    FROM   
    (
        SELECT 
            timefiledate AS `Date`, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE transactionCode= 'code1' AND timefiledate = `date`)AS code1,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE transactionCode= 'code2' AND timefiledate = `date`)AS code2, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE transactionCode IN ('code1', 'code2') AND timefiledate = `date`)AS Total
            (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(elapsedTime)) FROM tableName WHERE transactionCode IN ('code1', 'code2') AND timefiledate = `date`) AS TotalElapsedTime
        FROM bartran

    ) AS A

    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31'
    GROUP BY `date`;
```